# In D&D 3.5, can you cast with a fractional caster level?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, caster-level

Not that it's likely to come up very often, but I saw [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205963/25662) suggesting that you can reduce your caster level, and I realized I didn't know: **can you reduce that caster level to (say) 2.5?**

In general, caster level is strongly tied to whole numbers. The round-down rule and the whole-number outcomes of a d20 roll significantly reduce how often fractional caster levels would even matter. But "rarely relevant" is not the same as impossible, and the linked question provides one place that it might.

Is there anything even suggesting that you can't reduce your caster level to 2.5, so that *updraft* sends you exactly 25 feet into the air?

Comment: Your question, but we [generally don't put systems in titles](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/should-questions-include-system-setting-in-title-if-tagged-with-system-setting). No harm in keeping it, either.

Comment: @NautArch when we started burninating the tags I used most regularly, I started making sure that no relevant question info relies on tags (which is the default answer anyway).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### In general, and in this, you can't have fractions.

Unless specified otherwise, [all fractions are rounded](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#roundingFractions):

> In general, if you wind up with a fraction, round down, even if the fraction is one-half or larger.

As there's no exception for caster level, you can't have a fractional caster level.

Answer (score 3):

Your [Caster Level](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/castingSpells.htm#casterLevel) is described as:

> A spell’s power often depends on its caster level, which for most spellcasting characters is equal to your class level in the class you’re using to cast the spell.
>
> You can cast a spell at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level.
>
> In the event that a class feature, domain granted power, or other special ability provides an adjustment to your caster level, that adjustment applies not only to effects based on caster level (such as range, duration, and damage dealt) but also to your caster level check to overcome your target’s spell resistance and to the caster level used in dispel checks (both the dispel check and the DC of the check).

To this GM, that's very strong evidence that caster level is a whole number, just like class levels.

Comment: That's the exact passage that made me ask this. Let me clarify the question.